# Python Calculator, No Answer

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, if-statement

I am very much interested in *Python* and I decided to learn it.
I covered many things but I am stuck when try to make a Calculator in which we just need to type the numbers and the operation type

For Example- `10 ^ 2`

The thing that happens is I get no answer. And i use *Command Prompt*
for the output.

My Code looks like this:

```
 # Calculator



print " "
print "  Calculator  "
print " "

num = int(raw_input(">> ")).split()

num1 = int(num[0])

op = num[1]

num2 = int(num[2])

if (op=='+'):

    print ">>>", num1 + num2
elif (op=='-'):

    print ">>>", num1 - num2
elif (op=='*'):

    print ">>>", num1 * num2
elif (op=='/'):

    print ">>>", num1 / num2
elif (op=='^'):

    print ">>>", pow(num1,num2)
elif (op=='%'):

    print ">>>", num1 % num2
```

I use Python 2.7.

Please Help Me For The Same.

Comment: Whats your input look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `int` cast, that is

```
num = raw_input(">> ").split() # remove the int cast
```

Output will then be:

```
>> 10 ^ 2
>>> 100
```

Comment: I think using `split()` without specifying the `sep` argument is closer to what the question is looking for. See the docs on `str.split()`[https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split]. It will treat "runs of consecutive whitespace [...] as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace"

Comment: @HelloWorld all the best! Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
num = int(raw_input(">> ")).split()
```

To

```
num = raw_input(">> ").split()
```

If you enter `2 ^ 10`, for example, `num` will now be the array `['2', '^', '10']` and the rest of your code will work.

If you do `int()` on your `raw_input` it will not work since you are trying to convert a string like `"2 ^ 10"` to an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(raw_input(">> ")).split()
```

should be changed to

```
num = (raw_input(">> ")).split()
```

you cannot split a number at least for what I know